# JPanel API: Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, jpanel

So I was reading the [`JPanel` API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html) and saw the fields about inherited methods for example, and I saw three boxes of methods that `JPanel` inherits. Now, knowing what I learned the first week of the Comp. Sci. intro class, `JPanel` can only inherit methods from its `superclass`, so then how does `JPanel` seem to have three `superclasses`? Am I reading this wrong, if so, how does `JPanel` inherit from three different classes? Note, there are four boxes of inherited methods, but I know that everything descends from `Object`, so I got that, what I don't understand is how JPanel can also be the subclass of the other three classes listed preceding `Object`.

Again, probably the stupidest question to ever be asked, but I'm very confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. JPanel inherits from JComponent
2. JComponent inherits from Container
3. Container inherits from Component
4. Component inherits from Object

So yes, JPanel inherits the methods from JComponent, Container, Component and Object.

This is the basis of `inheritance`. Start with the Java tutorial on [Object Oriented Programming Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/index.html).

Comment: Oh, is this inheritance through composition? Inheritance and Graphics are my weaknesses unfortunately